# Angular routeProvider without "#"

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I've got problem with routProvider in Angular. Loding content by clicking on menu works fine but after refreshing localhost/blog there is an error occured "object not found". Console shows error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'controller'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
        .when('/blog', {
             templateUrl: 'templates/blog.html'
         })
         .otherwise({
             templateUrl: 'templates/404.html'
         })
         $locationProvider.html5Mode({
             enabled: true,
             requireBase: false
     });
})


<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog">Blogs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe, but how to fix this?

Comment: Problem solved - look at the top of the post